# How to get Orders for specific product's attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I want to apply filter as follow, I want to get All orders having product of specific attribute, my product has a custom attribute ii_id,my sql query may be like this "get all orders having product where ii_id==123",  here more than two tables (sales_flat_order,sales_flat_order_item,and tables for product)are involved, I am bit confused, how should I do this?

Comment: This can be simplify, If I can get all product_id's in array, having  ii_id==123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$productId = 123;
$orders = array();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $productId))
    ->load();
foreach($collection as $orderItem) {
  echo $orderItem->getOrder();
}
```

Comment: Bro I don't have productId, I want order collection in return,

Comment: I just have ii_id value, nothing else, filter is based on ii_id,ii-id can be single or multiple select type

Comment: As i mentioned in my comment "if I have all product_id's in array, having ii_id==123 or ii_id=1234", then My problem by your answer will be solved

Comment: I am using this for refereance, How can I get just entity_id means product_id  from this       '$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToFilter('ii_id',1);'

Comment: `$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') ->getCollection() ->addAttributeToFilter('ii_id',1);` and `$orderCollection->getAllIds();` will return you array of product ids.

Comment: `->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('in' => $productId))` use that as a filter.